# How to solve IO error in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

i want inherit model in odoo, and i upgrade my modul, error showing like this :

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/misc.py", line 199, in file_open
return _fileopen(name, mode=mode, basedir=rtp, pathinfo=pathinfo, basename=basename)File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/misc.py", line 246, in _fileopen
raise IOError('File not found: %s' % basename)IOError: File not found: estate_vehicle/views/inherit_transfertomn_spb_view
```

this my python code :

```
class InheritSPB(models.Model):

_inherit ='estate.nursery.seeddo'

timesheet_ids = fields.One2many('estate.timesheet.activity.transport','owner_id','Timesheet ids')
```

And this my view code :

```
record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherit_view_field_view_timesheet_transfermn_activity">
         <field name="name">Inherit timesheet SPB</field>
         <field name="model">estate.nursery.seeddo</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="estate_nursery.view_form_seeddo"/>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
             <xpath expr="//page[@name='detail_transportir'']" position="after">
                 <page string="Vehicle Information">
                     <tree>
                         <field name="vehicle_timesheet_ids" track_visibility="onchange" attrs="{'required': [('state','=','draft')],
                                'readonly': [('state','=','done')]}"
                                context="{'tree_view_ref' : 'estate_nursery.view_tree_timesheet_activity_transport',
                                       'default_dc_type' : 2}"/>
                     </tree>
                 </page>
             </xpath>
         </field>
     </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, file should be inherit_transfertomn_spb_view.xml

You need to check your files in module *estate_vehicle* *views* folder with *inherit_transfertomn_spb_view.xml* file name is available or not.

Now check your `__openerp__.py`

For example:

```
"data" : [
     #new of file with proper destination
     views/inherit_transfertomn_spb_view.xml
]
```